# Android: Getting all cities, towns, postal codes in near

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location, google-places-api

I need to find all cities, towns or postal codes in radius of 20 km from place specified by latitude and longitude.

I've tried [Places search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=pl) from Google Places API with this query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=53.09022140,21.21483510&radius=20000&types=(locality|postal_code)&sensor=false&key=myKey
```

but this seems not to work with geocode places (only business results are presented).

I've also read about Place Searches in [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of Google Maps JavaScript API v3, but I'm not sure if this is appropriate for Android Application (I have a http/php server, but I'm not sure how can I use it with my Android App). Can I use it directly from my application?

Maybe I could achieve it using other service? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found its solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is very old but since no one has yet answered it I figured I'd share how I solve this problem.

There are a couple of ways that you can solve this. The first is by creating your own places database using information provided here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

This isn't too hard, but could be a pain if you don't have the time.

There are also a whole lot of 3rd party services that could do this for you. I run one such service called https://geo-info.co/

We do almost exactly what you need in this case.

https://geo-info.co/53.09022140,21.21483510

Will return the nearest city to those coordinates as well as the 10 other closest neighboring cities.

```
{
    "city": "Perzanki-Borek",
    "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
    "community2": "141104",
    "country": "PL",
    "county": "Powiat makowski",
    "county2": "1411",
    "latitude": "53.0902",
    "longitude": "21.2113",
    "nearby": [
        {
            "city": "Grabowo",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0809",
            "longitude": "21.2201",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-212"
        },
        {
            "city": "Papierny Borek",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0885",
            "longitude": "21.1844",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-214"
        },
        {
            "city": "W\u00f3lka Rakowska",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.1019",
            "longitude": "21.1767",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-214"
        },
        {
            "city": "Amelin",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0646",
            "longitude": "21.2376",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-212"
        },
        {
            "city": "Raki",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0766",
            "longitude": "21.1691",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-214"
        },
        {
            "city": "Bagienice-Folwark",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0644",
            "longitude": "21.1855",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-212"
        },
        {
            "city": "El\u017cbiecin",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0909",
            "longitude": "21.161",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-214"
        },
        {
            "city": "Adamczycha",
            "community": "Gmina Baranowo",
            "community2": "141501",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat ostro\u0142\u0119cki",
            "county2": "1415",
            "latitude": "53.1072",
            "longitude": "21.2633",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-320"
        },
        {
            "city": "Bagienice Szlacheckie",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0553",
            "longitude": "21.2046",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-212"
        },
        {
            "city": "Ruzieck",
            "community": "Gmina Krasnosielc",
            "community2": "141104",
            "country": "PL",
            "county": "Powiat makowski",
            "county2": "1411",
            "latitude": "53.0812",
            "longitude": "21.2733",
            "state": "Mazovia",
            "state2": "78",
            "zipcode": "06-212"
        }
    ],
    "state": "Mazovia",
    "state2": "78",
    "zipcode": "06-212"
}
```